# Redefine Password in Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel

I don't know how to deal with the reset password link, I'm using default, but hosting doesn't work and local host with ip mailtrap.io works great.

I get 404
Not Found after clicking link received in email.

My .env file is configured as the other previous project that worked very well, but was laravel 5.2

my route:

```
Route::get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm');
Route::post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.email');
Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.request');
Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset')->name('password.reset');
```

My ForgotPasswordController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\SendsPasswordResetEmails;

class ForgotPasswordController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Reset Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller is responsible for handling password reset emails and
    | includes a trait which assists in sending these notifications from
    | your application to your users. Feel free to explore this trait.
    |
    */

    use SendsPasswordResetEmails;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }
}
```

my ResetPasswordController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;

class ResetPasswordController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Reset Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller is responsible for handling password reset requests
    | and uses a simple trait to include this behavior. You're free to
    | explore this trait and override any methods you wish to tweak.
    |
    */

    use ResetsPasswords;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after resetting their password.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }
}
```

---

I resolved by changing just `"MAIL_ENCRYPTION = null" to "MAIL_ENCRYPTION = tls"`

Comment: I don't have HOST_NAME, but APP_NAME and it is set to yes

Comment: sorry sorry, I was asking about APP_URL.

Comment: oh yes, she already has the hosting domain "APP_URL = blabla.blabla.com"

Comment: And what is the exact link you are getting in your email?

Comment: https://blabla.blabla.com/public/index.php?token=d4f978a75491ef615af4b2b5571655547c1f5542853f711fa307ba2ad339472a&email=atilaoliveira80%40myemail.com  404 | Not Found

Comment: you are accessing your site pages using `public/index.php/route-uri` or only `/route-uri` ?

Comment: I don't really know how this public / index.php ended up in the reset link url

Comment: I know it was like this when I hosted the project and had to leave mailtrap.io and put the hosting settings

Comment: I think, you understand now, what I was trying to point out. now need to know, if your urls are like `https://blabla.blabla.com/public/.index.php/about` or `https://blabla.blabla.com/about` and make it consistent, I think doing that will work fine for you.

Comment: got it, I don't use public not, I use https://blabla.blabla.com/dashboard my files are inside views

Comment: good, Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Accordingly to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57952231/redefine-password-in-laravel-5-8#comment102317235_57952231) it looks like you have wrong web server (apache/nginx) configuration. If you are using apache, look on mod rewrite.

Comment: yes, I had already resolved by changing just "MAIL_ENCRYPTION = null" to "MAIL_ENCRYPTION = tls"